# Android Studio "Blank Activity" template not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-optionsmenu

I'm new to Android development, so please pardon me if it is a silly question.

I'm using **Android Studio** for developing the app. I just created a sample app using it. I chose "Blank Activity" Template.

My Issue is when I ran that on Emulator the screen looks like:

[image: Emulator]

When I tap on the Option menu, the app crashes. I couldn't figure out the issue.
I didn't changed anything in the project or didn't even write a line of code in it.

Also the UI design shows some rendering error:

[image: Rendering issue]

As you can see, I didn't changed anything in the UI. I have another project created few weeks back and it works perfectly, but the issue is happening for the newly created project.

More Info:

1. Android Studio 1.0.2
2. Minimum SDK Version 15

**Logcat**

```
01-08 23:13:40.083    7178-7178/com.XXX E/InputEventReceiver﹕ Exception dispatching input event.
01-08 23:13:40.086    7178-7178/com.XXX E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-08 23:13:40.132    7178-7178/com.XXX E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.res.ColorStateList.getColorForState(int[], int)' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.activateHotspot(RippleDrawable.java:413)
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.setActive(RippleDrawable.java:229)
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.onStateChange(RippleDrawable.java:207)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:566)
            at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15576)
            at android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged(ImageView.java:1006)
            at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:15594)
            at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:6789)
            at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:6767)
            at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:9044)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8073)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2198)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2717)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2159)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8263)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4013)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3892)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3583)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5656)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5627)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.
01-08 23:13:40.134    7178-7178/com.midhun.mp.creditdebit D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-08 23:13:40.167    7178-7178/com.midhun.mp.creditdebit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.midhun.mp.creditdebit, PID: 7178
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.res.ColorStateList.getColorForState(int[], int)' on a null object reference
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.activateHotspot(RippleDrawable.java:413)
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.setActive(RippleDrawable.java:229)
            at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.onStateChange(RippleDrawable.java:207)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:566)
            at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:15576)
            at android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged(ImageView.java:1006)
            at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:15594)
            at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:6789)
            at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:6767)
            at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:9044)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8073)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2259)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2001)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2198)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2717)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2159)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8263)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4013)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3892)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3583)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3481)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3454)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5656)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5627)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5761)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Can anybody help me to find the issue ? I'm a newbie in Android development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press Alt+6 (windows), it will open a window. When app crashes it would show some log in red color. Please post that.

Comment: No its not that. Use Cmd+6 on mac

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, seems there was something wrong with the android preview version. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584131/material-design-on-nexus-5-with-android-l

Comment: what is your taget sdk version in manifest? If its 21 see if you need an update.

Comment: @Rohit5k2:  compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21